# Mapping fetched JSON Object in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-hooks

What I'm trying to achieve is an admin page fetching users data from a local endpoint.

- Here what I can see in localhost:3000/api/users:
  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVGAN.png)
- This is the component which should display the list of users:

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    
    import "./admin-users.styles.scss";
    
    const AdminUsers = () => {
      const [listUsers, setListUsers] = useState(null);
      const [error, setError] = useState("error");
    
      React.useEffect(() => {
        listUsers === null && retrieveUsers();
      });
    
      const retrieveUsers = () => {
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/users", {
          method: "get",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((retrievedUsers) => {
            if (retrievedUsers) {
              setListUsers(retrievedUsers);
            } else {
              setError("error active");
            }
          });
      };
    
      return (
        <div className="admin-users">
          <h2>Users Table</h2>
          
          {console.log(listUsers)}
    
          <div className={error}>
            <p>Error fetching data</p>
          </div>
    
          {!listUsers === null &&
            listUsers.map((user) => {
              console.log(user);
              return <span>User</span>;
            })}
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default AdminUsers;
```

- I can console.log the list of users, but I cannot map through the listUsers: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BShzD.png)

  I think the problem stands on the type of object I'm trying to map; Tried looking for solutions but cannot find anything helpful..

Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Comment: what is `User` i n `<span>User</span>;`

Comment: what is the problem here? when you do console.log(user), that should have correct data which would be an object based on your example. Also why doing `!listUsers === null` instead you can do `{listUsers && listUsers.map(() => {})}`

Comment: If `listUsers` is an array, there's no reason you shouldn't be able to `map`. I think what you want to do is just this: `<span>{user.name}</span>;`

Comment: For some reason before wasn't displaying if only writing the string 'user', which I put there for testing.. Now I changed to be {user.name} and it displays just fine! Thanks all

Comment: @ale917k Ah, yes. `user` is an object and you must use one of its properties to display the corresponding value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update this line of code:

```js
{!listUsers === null &&
    listUsers.map((user) => {
        console.log(user);
        return <span>{user}</span>;
    })
}
```

Comment: For some reason before wasn't displaying if only writing the string 'user', which I put there for testing.. Now I changed to be {user.name} and it displays just fine! Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Replace `return <span>User</span>;` with `return <span>{user}</span>;`

Comment: Curly Braces `{user}`

Comment: Well, `user`, seems like an `object` from the screenshot. So I guess, he wants to do {user.name}

Comment: For some reason before wasn't displaying if only writing the string 'user', which I put there for testing.. Now I changed to be {user.name} and it displays just fine! Thanks all